# Solve and equation containing $\sinh$ and $\cosh$

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to know how I can solve this or plot a versus b ?

```
Solve[ Sqrt[a] Cosh[1.2 Log[1.65 Sqrt[1/a]]] == Sqrt[-b] Sinh[1.2 Log[1.65 Sqrt[-(1/b)]]], b]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your current code mentions that `Solve` tried to rationalize your floating-point  constants. If you try to do that by hand, then Solve will return `Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

However, you can use `ContourPlot` to obtain a plot as a function of $a$ and $b$:

```
ContourPlot[
  Sqrt[a] Cosh[12/10 Log[165/100 Sqrt[1/a]]] == Sqrt[-b] Sinh[12/10 Log[165/100 Sqrt[-(1/b)]]],
  {a, 0, 8}, {b, -1/8, 0}, MaxRecursion -> 6
]
```

[image: 2D contour plot of the solution of the equation in OP]

Answer (score 4):

We can help `Solve` by converting the equation to a polynomial one.

```
eqn = Sqrt[a] Cosh[1.2 Log[1.65 Sqrt[1/a]]] == 
   Sqrt[-b] Sinh[1.2 Log[1.65 Sqrt[-(1/b)]]];

(* replace constants with symbols *)
coeff = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[eqn, _Real, Infinity] -> {c1, c2} // 
  Thread
(*  {1.2 -> c1, 1.65 -> c2}  *)

(* here's what the equation looks like *)
eqn /. coeff
```

> ```
> (*
> Sqrt[a] Cosh[c1 Log[Sqrt[1/a] c2]] == 
>  Sqrt[-b] Sinh[c1 Log[Sqrt[-(1/b)] c2]]
> *)
> ```

To get a polynomial equation, we rational the coefficients.  Only `c1` needs to be rationalized.  We also convert the rational exponents to integers by raising the variables to the 10th power.  This will introduce extraneous solutions which we will have to filter out.

```
Reverse@Rationalize@First@coeff
(*  c1 -> 6/5  *)

(* here's the polynomial equation *)
Simplify[
  eqn /. coeff /. Reverse@Rationalize@First@coeff /. {a -> u^10, 
     b -> -v^10} // TrigToExp,
  a > 0 && b < 0 && u > 0 && v > 0] // PowerExpand
```

> ```
> (*
>   c2^(6/5) (u - v) == (u v (u^11 + v^11))/c2^(6/5)
> *)
> ```

```
vsol = Solve[
   Simplify[
     eqn /. coeff /. Reverse@Rationalize@First@coeff /. {a -> u^10, 
        b -> -v^10} // TrigToExp, a > 0 && b < 0 && u > 0 && v > 0] //
     PowerExpand, v];
```

Now check the solutions (one can use the tooltip in the front end if the legend is not clear enough):

```
Plot[
 eqn /. Equal -> Subtract /. b -> -Values[vsol]^10 /. 
      Reverse@Last@coeff /. u -> a^(1/10) // RealExponent // 
   MapIndexed[Tooltip] // Evaluate,
 {a, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {1, -18}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The second and twelfth are solutions (over some interval), but the twelfth is complex-valued.  The second one is the desired solution.

```
Plot[
-Values[vsol][[2]]^10 /. Reverse@Last@coeff /. u -> a^(1/10),
 {a, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Thus

```
bsol = -Values[vsol][[2]]^10 /. Reverse@Last@coeff /. u -> a^(1/10) // First
```

> ```
> (*
> -Root[1.82381 a^(1/10) + (-1.82381 - 0.548301 a^(6/5)) #1 - 
>     0.548301 a^(1/10) #1^12 &, 2]^10
> *)
> ```

Note that the 10th power arose from the rationalization of `1.2`.  If `1.2` is approximate, then the solution, while symbolic, is only approximate too.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get solution in terms of root expression with variable substituion. (Use onesided eq.)

```
f[a_, b_] = 
 Sqrt[a] Cosh[
      1.2 Log[1.65 Sqrt[1/a]]] - (Sqrt[-b] Sinh[
       1.2 Log[1.65 Sqrt[-(1/b)]]]) // Rationalize // 
  FullSimplify[#, a >= 0 && b <= 0] &

(*   Sqrt[a] Cosh[3/5 Log[(400 a)/1089]] - 
 Sqrt[-b] Sinh[3/5 Log[-(1089/(400 b))]]   *)
```

Substitute the arguments of Sinh and Cosh.

```
sola = First@Solve[aa == 3/5 Log[(400 a)/1089] && a > 0, a, Reals]

(*   {a -> 1089/400 E^(5 aa/3)}   *)

solb = First@Solve[bb == 3/5 Log[-(1089/(400 b))] && b < 0, b, Reals]

f2[aa_, bb_] = 
 f[a, b] /. sola /. solb // Simplify[#, Element[{aa, bb}, Reals]] &

(*   33/20 (E^(5 aa/6) Cosh[aa] - E^(-5 bb/6) Sinh[bb])   *)

sol3 = First@Solve[f2[aa, bb] == 0, bb, Reals]

(*   {bb -> 6 Log[Root[-1 - 2 E^(5 aa/6) Cosh[aa] #1^11 + #1^12 &, 2]]}   *)

sol4 = sol3 /. aa -> 3/5 Log[(400 a)/1089] /. 
  bb -> 3/5 Log[-(1089/(400 b))]

solb = First@Solve[sol4 /. Rule -> Equal, b] // FullSimplify

(*   {b -> -(1089/(
   400 Root[-33 - 40 Sqrt[a] Cosh[3/5 Log[(400 a)/1089]] #1^11 + 
       33 #1^12 &, 2]^10))}   *)

Plot[b /. solb, {a, 0, 5}]
```